# Java engine for a 2d game with non pixel style

Tags: java, 2d

I'm currently making a concept of a new game and as I'm not so experienced in making games I have one BIG question:
Are there free engines supporting java with the help of which I could build a 2D game with HD graphics. Under HD i mean some different from pixel art ones. Because the more I googld the more I understood that most of the free engines are made for lightweight pixel graphics and my small experience shows that using them with high resolution pictures results in very poor performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 2D Game Engines in Java

- [Libgdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) - Windows, Linux, Mac, Android, BlackBerry, iOS, HTML
- [Slick2D](http://slick.ninjacave.com/) - Windows, Linux, Mac

Both are great 2D game engines. Don't worry about HD performance, both use opengl acceleration underneath. It should be more than sufficient for most games.

Hope this helps.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Java is not too great when it comes to graphics.
[You can try jogl](http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/) it is as graphically optimized as it gets. If you are looking to make super HD triple A title then you can't use java unfortunately.
However games are not all about graphics, but the actual content.

But your question still strikes me as odd, since [I have tried making 2D games](https://github.com/Quillion/GameEngine), and didn't encounter huge problems when using graphic intensive sprites.

Comment: You should be more precise when talking about graphics in Java. Swing isn't designed and optimized for games, its build-in hardware acceleration drives performance inconsistent across platforms whereas GLG2D allows to benefit of a better hardware acceleration with Swing. I'm sorry to contradict you but creating AAA games in Java is possible, Java has been used in commercial games since 1995, often with other languages. Megacorps Online (FPS), Salem (MMORPG), Tribal Trouble, Wakfu and Minecraft are some good examples of Java games.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to 2D games you don't really need an engine, you could just make it with a JLabel and make it an image. it is what i do with my 2D games. you will need an engine with 3D games though.

But if you do want an engine try java3D it works for 2D as i understand u can also use jmonkey engine it can also do 2D games or Slick2D.

Comment: Swing is enough for extremely simple games but when it becomes graphically non trivial, hardware acceleration becomes really helpful. Another solution consists in using GLG2D to get a better hardware acceleration with Swing.

Comment: As I see it 2D games are extremely simple unless you are trying to make a 2D grand theft auto, 3D games Defnatly need an engine though.

Comment: You can write your own 3D engine for pedagogical purposes but it will lead you to reinvent the wheel. It depends on what you really want to do.